# How to divide values from one column by another and print results in a new column?

Tags: linux, awk, text-processing

I am relatively new to `awk` so I have a simple question about doing division and print the results in a new column. For example:

```
head data

1   13273      .  G   C   563  5  .  25    128
1   202259     .  G   T   675  8  .  12    130
1   598934     .  C   C   756  9  .  17    231
1   634112     .  T   C   125  1  .  32    89
1   779762     .  G   A   675  5  .  28    187
```

I would like to divide column 9 by column 10 and print the results in a new column 11, preferably sort the new results from high to low. For example:

```
1   634112     .  T   C   125  1  .  32    89    0.360
1   13273      .  G   C   563  5  .  25    128   0.195
1   779762     .  G   A   675  5  .  28    187   0.150
1   202259     .  G   T   675  8  .  12    130   0.092
1   598934     .  C   C   756  9  .  17    231   0.074
```

I only know how to do it in R, but I wanted to learn how we can do it in `awk`. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Awk is quite expressive with respect to the first requirement. If you want a column 11, you can just invent it and set it equal to the result of dividing column 9 by column 10.

It's possible to do the sort in awk, but it's a bit of a pain so easier just to pipe to sort. The column command makes it prettier, nothing more than that.

```
$ awk '{$11 = $9 / $10}1' file | sort -nr -k 11 | column -t
1  634112  .  T  C  125  1  .  32  89   0.359551
1  13273   .  G  C  563  5  .  25  128  0.195312
1  779762  .  G  A  675  5  .  28  187  0.149733
1  202259  .  G  T  675  8  .  12  130  0.0923077
1  598934  .  C  C  756  9  .  17  231  0.0735931
```

If your output needs to be tab separated, you can set the `OFS` variable (and forget about the column command):

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{$11 = $9 / $10}1' file | sort -nr -k 11 
1   634112  .   T   C   125 1   .   32  89  0.359551
1   13273   .   G   C   563 5   .   25  128 0.195312
1   779762  .   G   A   675 5   .   28  187 0.149733
1   202259  .   G   T   675 8   .   12  130 0.0923077
1   598934  .   C   C   756 9   .   17  231 0.0735931
```

Finally, you can use `sprintf` to format that last column as in your sample output:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{$11 = sprintf("%.3f", $9 / $10)}1' file | sort -nr -k 11
1   634112  .   T   C   125 1   .   32  89  0.360
1   13273   .   G   C   563 5   .   25  128 0.195
1   779762  .   G   A   675 5   .   28  187 0.150
1   202259  .   G   T   675 8   .   12  130 0.092
1   598934  .   C   C   756 9   .   17  231 0.074
```

**UPDATE**:

As Ed Morton shows in his answer, the ternary operator `?:` can be used to protect against dividing by zero. Here I've put "UND" in column 11 to indicate "undefined", but of course you can just leave it blank or put some different value.

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{$11 = ($10 != 0) ? sprintf("%.3f", $9 / $10) : "UND"}1' file | sort -nr -k 11
1   634112  .   T   C   125 1   .   32  89  0.360
1   13273   .   G   C   563 5   .   25  128 0.195
1   779762  .   G   A   675 5   .   28  187 0.150
1   202259  .   G   T   675 8   .   12  130 0.092
1   598934  .   C   C   756 9   .   17  0   UND
```

At some point you might decide that the awk program is getting complicated enough that it's better off in its own file with an emphasis more on readability than compactness.

```
$ cat div.awk file 

BEGIN { OFS="\t"}

{
    if ($10 != 0) {
        quotient = $9 / $10
        $11 = sprintf("%.3f", quotient)
    }
    else {
        $11 = "UND"
    }
    print
}


$ awk -f div.awk file  | sort -nr -k 11
1   634112  .   T   C   125 1   .   32  89  0.360
1   13273   .   G   C   563 5   .   25  128 0.195
1   779762  .   G   A   675 5   .   28  187 0.150
1   202259  .   G   T   675 8   .   12  130 0.092
1   598934  .   C   C   756 9   .   17  0   UND
```

Comment: Thanks for your code! I wonder what we should do if $10 is zero? How to prevent getting an error?

Comment: You're welcome!  See update for one way of checking for zero.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for sorted_in:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ a[NR]=$0; v[NR]=$9/$10 }
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"
    for (i in v) {
        print a[i] "\t" v[i]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1   634112     .  T   C   125  1  .  32    89   0.359551
1   13273      .  G   C   563  5  .  25    128  0.195312
1   779762     .  G   A   675  5  .  28    187  0.149733
1   202259     .  G   T   675  8  .  12    130  0.0923077
1   598934     .  C   C   756  9  .  17    231  0.0735931
```

Change `v[NR]=$9/$10` to `v[NR]=($10==0 ? 0 : $9/$10)` or similar to protect against divide-by-zero if $10 can be zero.